# can a deployed war/application be edited?

Tags: java

I have an application/war deployed in server. Now at runtime I want to add an xml document to the war/application. can I do that? if yes, what is the path of an war/application for it to be added.

Comment: depends on which server. Usually they unpack war into some internal folder, you can edit those and restart AS. But much easier is just redeploy war..

Answer (score 1):

You have to repackage the WAR, redeploy, and bounce the server.  It's not that simple.

You can make that data available without the hassle if you put it in a database and have your application access it there.

Answer (score 0):

in the `webapps/WEB-INF` folder you can find the xml files

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the servlet container/application server.

If you are using Tomcat, wars are getting unpacked to the `webapps` directory inside the Tomcat directory.

1. Move `webapps/app` directory outside the `webapps` directory, what will cause an undeploy of `app`
2. Put your xml file into the `app` directory
3. Move `app` back to `webapps` what will cause a deploy